# Is it possible to limit the files accepted in a specific path with a regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to allow certain type of extensions in a specific drive (eg C:)

I have the below to restrich the file types

```
String pattern= "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(txt|doc))$)";
```

is it possible to allow the files only from C:

```
C:\UserTemp\aa.txt
```

Comment: what happens if the user doesn't have a `c` drive letter?

Comment: What are you using to list the files ?

Comment: It should not be accepted if the file is not from C:

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you need a regular expression for this?  Java has many cleaner ways of restricting files and file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "start of line" anchor (`^`) and place `C:` literally right after it. Please note that you may need to move `(?i)` to the start of the regex to make drive litter match case-insensitive.

```
String pattern= "(?i)^C:[^\\s]+(\\.(txt|doc))$";
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to allow the files only from C

Why you want to use patterns and regex, you can simply use StartWith like this :

```
str.startsWith("C")
```

This can allow any URL from the driver C

Comment: I would lik to have 2 checks here. firstly to chek if it is c drive and then to limit on file extensions

Comment: in this case there are also a method `endWith` to check the extension but i recommend the solution of @Dmitry Egorov it is good one and solve your problem